# How to access Platform Cache using REST API

Tags: rest-api, rest, platform-cache

I have a requirement to retrieve available resource and consumed resources for Platform Cache outside my salesforce org.
I was wondering if we can use REST API to retrieve this result ?

Given a try by using Metadata API (wsdl) with SOAPUI tool -
Using retrieve method, but needs help with pulling **PlatformCachePartition** as it is giving this error :

SOAP Response :

```
  <soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}retrieve</faultstring>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

SOAP Request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:met="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<soapenv:Header>
    <met:SessionHeader>
       <met:sessionId>xxxxxx</met:sessionId>
    </met:SessionHeader> 
</soapenv:Header>  
<soapenv:Body>
    <met:retrieve>
       <met:retrieveRequest>
         <met:apiVersion>51.0</met:apiVersion>
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:--> 
  <!--  <met:packageNames>
            </met:packageNames>
          <met:singlePackage>true</met:singlePackage>  -->
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
  <!--  <met:specificFiles>?</met:specificFiles>  -->
             <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <met:types>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <met:members>*</met:members>
              <met:name>PlatformCachePartition</met:name>
            </met:types> </br>
   <!--  <met:version>51.0</met:version>  -->
      </met:retrieveRequest>
   </met:retrieve>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: REST - you might be able to use Tooling's `executeAnonymous` and retrieve a debug log to see the "response" but that's a hack. You're better off with Metadata API (SOAP) on [PlatformCachePartition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformcachepartition.htm) or rolling your own REST API that uses Apex calls to interact with the cache.

Comment: I am getting this error <h2>Element types invalid at this location</h2> and unable to figure out the correct syntax
<br/>
         <met:retrieveRequest><br/>
            <met:apiVersion>51.0</met:apiVersion><br/>
            <met:singlePackage>true</met:singlePackage><br/>
               <met:types><br/>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:--><br/>
                  <met:members>PlatformCachePartition</met:members><br/>
                  <met:name>Metadata</met:name><br/>
               </met:types><br/>
               <met:version>51.0</met:version><br/>
         </met:r

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @identigral Done, please refer above