# Can we set the Platform Cache using API call

Tags: apex, rest-api, platform-cache

I have a requirement where I need to maintain/use few values through out the `session` and I am thinking to use `Platform Cache`. Since, we are getting these values from a 3rd party I am wondering if we 3rd party can make an API call to set the `platform cache` value? moreover this is a question whether `Platform Cache` can be set via any API call.

If this is not possible then I would have to make an API call to the 3rd party and store the response in `Platform Cache`.

Comment: You definitely can stand up a custom REST or SOAP endpoint for this need if all else fails.

Comment: There's no out of the box REST API for this. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/333420/how-to-access-platform-cache-using-rest-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better architecture will be you making a simple apex callout to the third party site and setting the session cache than having the third party reach into Salesforce.

```
// Instantiate a new http object
Http h = new Http();

 // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');

// Send the request, and return a response
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

// Populate with session cache
if(res.getBody() != null) {
   Cache.Session.put('response', res.getBody());
}
```